# What is the wrong of this code?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

It doesn't list with `ng-repeat`. What is wrong with this code snippet?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<body>

<div ng-app="MyApp">

    <div ng-init="courses = [{"Number":"CREOO11","Name":"Design Pattern 101","Instructor":"Yunus Emre KESKIN"},
                             {"Number":"CREOO12","Name":"Design Pattern 102","Instructor":"Yunus Emre KESKIN"},
                             {"Number":"CREOO13","Name":"Design Pattern 103","Instructor":"Yunus Emre KESKIN"}]">

        <div class="row">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Course Number </th>
                    <th> Course Name   </th>
                    <th> Instructor    </th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="c in courses">

                    <td> {{c.Number}} </td>
                    <td> {{c.Name}} </td>
                    <td> {{c.Instructor}} </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: see the errors on console.

Comment: = **"** courses = [{ **"** N

Comment: how should it be ?

Answer (score 1):

There were two issues in the above code:
1. MyApp angular module is not available while you have used it in your html file
2. Way to initialized courses is not correct

### Correct code is attached below:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.4.8/angular.min.js"></script>
<script>
  angular.module('MyApp', [])
  .controller('MyCntrl', function($scope) {
       $scope.courses = [{"Number":"CREOO11","Name":"Design Pattern 101","Instructor":"Yunus Emre KESKIN"},
                             {"Number":"CREOO12","Name":"Design Pattern 102","Instructor":"Yunus Emre KESKIN"},
                             {"Number":"CREOO13","Name":"Design Pattern 103","Instructor":"Yunus Emre KESKIN"}];
   });
</script>
<body>

<div ng-app="MyApp">

    <div ng-controller="MyCntrl">

        <div class="row">
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <th> Course Number </th>
                    <th> Course Name   </th>
                    <th> Instructor    </th>
                </tr>

                <tr ng-repeat="c in courses">

                    <td> {{c.Number}} </td>
                    <td> {{c.Name}} </td>
                    <td> {{c.Instructor}} </td>

                </tr>
            </table>
        </div>

    </div>

</div>


</body>
</html>
```